# why my candles timezone have difference from the timezone I set?

Tags: python, timezone, metatrader5

```
utc_from = pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens').localize(datetime(2021, 8, 30))
utc_to = pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens').localize(datetime.now())
print("utc_from::",utc_from)
print("utc_to::",utc_to)
rates = mt5.copy_rates_range("XAUUSD_i", mt5.TIMEFRAME_H1, utc_from, utc_to)
print("rates>>>")
print(rates)

# display each element of obtained data in a new line
print("Display obtained data 'as is'")
counter=0
for rate in rates:
    counter+=1
    if counter<=10:
        print(rate)
```

I set the timezone on Europe/Athens. when I print date_to it shows me 2021-08-30 16:46. it’s the same with my mt5 time but at this time it shows me the last candle at 2021-08-30 10:00:00. Why is it behind the current time?

[image]

Comment: you walked into `pytz`'s "*localize trap*". use `localize` ! - e.g. `pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens').localize(datetime(2021, 8, 30))`. Or avoid `pytz` and use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), no such worries there. Also, to get "now" in a certain time zone, use e.g. `datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens'))`.

Comment: @MrFuppes I tried different modes that you mentioned but I did not succeed

Comment: Sorry but I can't tell from your code sample if anything else goes wrong. Too many variables I can't judge. The above was just an obvious mistake.

Comment: @MrFuppes I edited it to simple code. if it's possible please check it again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library but from the docs, it seems copy_rates_range expects UTC? Anyway, I see the bug I pointed out also exists in their docs...